# Which photo sharing site or photo hosting service can post full size photos to a Facebook page?

Tags: service-recommendation, presentation, facebook, promotion

Instead of posting on Facebook directly, I would like to be able to share my photos on Facebook from a photo sharing site to Facebook.  I was hoping Zenfolio could do this easily but their Facebook integration is not what I was hoping for; my bad for not actually trying it out before launching my site.

All that Zenfolio does is post a standard link with an icon to Facebook rather than a facebook-size photo. This link with an icon is not an appealing presentation to my Facebook Page audience.

I use also Fine Art America (FAA) and 500px. FAA works similarly to Zenfolio, albeit in a more streamlined manner, but it too ultimately only posts a link with an icon.  500px does the best job from all 3 services I use with 2 issues: link is still displayed along the bottom of the photo which crops the photo, and the photo itself is aggressively downsampled  to the point of being unusable for presentation.

I am willing to consolidate my services to use a single paid service that is capable of posting full size linked images to my Facebook page.

EDIT: Here is an example of from a page of a known Photo Magazine that contains a near full size image along with a link. It seems the image is still crisp and not overly down-sampled. This is something i would like to be able to do:

[image: Screen capture - Facebook Page]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Facebook, not Photography as defined in the [help center](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: It's about displaying photography on Facebook... So i beleive it falls under "techniques and best practices"which is the 4th item down that list. Facebook, being currently one of the largest, most popular online "gallery", is a way to show photography and I believe it qualifies. If not then every question about showing photography online or in a physical gallery, framing and printing of photography would be off topic, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook themselves have a guide that answers the *why* [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images).

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on
>   high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that
>   are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.
>
> If your image is smaller than 600 x 315 px, it will still display in
>   the link page post, but the size will be much smaller.

Of course it is very easy to achieve the recommended resolution if you are self-hosting a blog or website, but many hosted photo sharing sites also have this ability.

Specifically, I tested this out using both Smugmug and Flickr and both do provide the larger preview images:

Flickr Link:

[image]

SmugMug Link:

[image]

Comment: Thanks David!  Smugmug link looks good. Flickr looks awesome except for the Flickr.com and I am currently not on Flickr.  I was deciding whether to go with Smugmug or Zenfolio and chose Zenfolio and mostly dislike it. I am going to consider a blog and switching to Smugmug next year. BTW, nice photos!

Answer (score 1):

What I generally do is just put direct links to the full size image on my Facebook page.  This results in the oneboxing kicking in and automatically converting it to an image like you see there.  I don't personally use a paid service, but rather put my images on my owncloud instance which I run myself, but there is no reason you shouldn't be able to use a similar style of linking for any hosting site that supports hot linking (linking directly to an image from an external URL).

I forget exactly how you get the description in, but I believe it generally involves making a page with particular markup.  I know my wordpress blog's integration is capable of such posts if I have a photo associated with the post, but I'm not sure exactly how it does it technically.  If you just want images though, then just supplying the direct image URL should work well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a cloud service with google drive and I don't think i can get a direct link there. (works better - i get a full size icon but also obscured by the image file name link)  I am able to get a direct link from Zenfolio but only certain smaller image sizes work in Facebook (up to 580 x 387) and clicking the image redirects to the direct image.  I am hoping to redirect to where the image is presented on the website so users can comment or place an order. I may have to just post a link to larger view instead of trying to bend technology to my will...